# Determine the boundary $R$ of the area $D_2 $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Determine the boundary $R$ of the area $D_2 =$ {$(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, x > 0$}.

a) $R =$ {$x^2 + y^2 = 1, x \geq 0$} $\cup$ {($x, y) : x = 0, -1 < y < 1$}.

b) $R = ${$x^2 + y^2 = 1, x > 0$} $\cup$ {$(x, y) : x = 0, -1 < y < 1$}.

I picked **b** because in the definition of the boundary of the area, it says that $x>0$. Not to mention the fact even in the alternative **a** it says: {($x, y) : x = 0, -1 < y < 1$} and then at the same time it says: ${$x^2 + y^2 = 1, x > 0$}. Anyways can someone explain to me why I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two choices only differ for $x=0$ in the first set.

Note that
$$
\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \text{ and } x = 0 \}
= \{ (0,1) \;,\; (0,-1) \}
$$
I think it is sufficiently obvious that these points lie in the boundary of $D_2$. For instance, drawing an open ball about each, the inside of those balls always intersects the semicircle. (You can play with this in this Desmos demo: [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nm5f3suau9).)

[image]

You should also see that $(0,1),(0,-1)$ are not in the first set.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about open balls. The definition of a boundary point was that if the area of an open ball is inside and outside. Is it why they included $x=0$?

Comment: Yes. Notice that no matter the radius of a ball at those points (those being $(0,y)$ for **any** $y \in [-1,1]$), we have part inside and part outside.

Answer (score 2):

The closure of the set is $\{(x,y) \, | \, x^2+y^2 \leq 1, x \geq 0\}=D_2 \cup \{(0,y) \, | \, -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$.

The interior of the set is $\{(x,y) \, | \, x^2+y^2 < 1, x>0\}=D_2-\{(x,y) \, | \, x^2+y^2=1\}$. So, boundary is the set difference (closure - interior).